# Nested class template type alias

Tags: c++, inner-classes, type-alias

This might be an easy question, but I can't seem to figure out the syntax to define a type alias for nested class templates.

Basically, I have:

```cpp
template<class T>
struct Outer {
    template<class U = T>
    struct Inner {};
}
```

I want to be able to access the Inner class as a type from outside the class definition.
I've tried:

```cpp
template<class T> 
using Inner = typename Outer<T>::Inner;
```

or

```cpp
template<class T, class U = T> 
using Inner = typename Outer<T>::Inner<U>;
```

But that didn't work.

How should this be done actually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need extra `template`:

```
template<class T, class U = T> 
using Inner = typename Outer<T>::template Inner<U>;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/M3dd5haTa)